# C#/.NET Most performant way to call a method dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, performance, reflection

We are developing a system, which reads commands from a tcp/ip stream and then executes those commands. Commands consist of a method call on an object also identified by an id int the command. You could think of a command as the information of an element id (addressing element we want to call a the command on) and an command id (addressing the method which should be called on the element). Additionally we also have the issue that we need to check some kind of permissions on every command and also how this command should be executed. (Should it be started in a new `Thread`, etc.)

An example of how such a command call could look like would be this:

```
class Callee
{
    public void RegularCall(int command, parameters)
    {
        switch (command)
        {
            case 1: // Comand #1
                // Check if the permissions allow this command to be called.
                // Check if it should be outsourced to the ThreadPool and
                // call it accordingly. +Other Checks.
                // Finally execute command #1.
                break;
            case 2: // Comand #2
                // Check if the permissions allow that command to be called.
                // Check if it should be outsourced to the ThreadPool and
                // call it accordingly. +Other Checks.
                // Finally execute command #2.
                break;
            // Many more cases with various combinations of permissions and
            // Other flags.
        }
    }
}
```

And somewhere:

```
static Dictionary<int, Callee> callees = new Dictionary<int, Callee>();

static void CallMethod(int elementId, int commandId, parameters)
{
    callees[elementId].RegularCall(commandId, parameters);
}
```

However, this approach is some kind of unelegant:

- This may be error prone due to copying the same code over and over again.
- In some circumstances it's hard to see, which commands exist and what their flags are.
- The command method is full of checks which could have made outside the method.

My first approach was by using reflection, which would have looked that way:

```
class Callee
{
    [Command(1)]
    [Permissions(0b00111000)]
    [UseThreadPool]
    public void SpeakingNameForCommand1(parameters)
    {
        // Code for command #1.
    }

    [Command(2)]
    [Permissions(0b00101011)]
    public void SpeakingNameForCommand2(parameters)
    {
        // Code for command #2.
    }

    // Again, many more commands.
}
```

This code must have been initialized with some reflection heavy code:

1. Find all classes which may represent an element.
2. Find all methods which have a command attribute, etc.
3. Store all those information in a dictionary, including the corresponding `MethodInfo`.

A call of a received command would look like this, where `CommandInfo` is a class containing all the information required for the call (`MethodInfo`, run in `ThreadPool`, permissions...):

```
static Dictionary<int, CommandInfo> commands = new Dictionary<int, CommandInfo>();

static void CallMethod(int elementId, int commandId)
{
    CommandInfo ci = commands[commandId];

    if (ci.Permissions != EVERYTHING_OK)
        throw ...;

    if (ci.UseThreadPool)
        ThreadPool.Queue...(delegate { ci.MethodInfo.Invoke(callees[elementId], params); });
    else
        ci.MethodInfo.Invoke(callees[elementId], params);
}
```

When I micro-benchmark this, the call to `MethodInfo.Invoke` is about 100x slower than the direct call. **The question is: Is there a faster way of calling those "command" methods, without losing the elegance of the attributes defining the way how those commands should be called?**

I also tried deriving a delegate from the `MethodInfo`. However, this didn't work well, because I need to be able to call the method on any instance of the `Callee` class and don't want to reserve the memory for the delegate for every possible element * commands. (There will be many elements.)

Just to make this clear: `MethodInfo.Invoke` is 100x slower than the function call including the `switch`/`case` statement. This excludes the time to walk over all classes, methods and attributes, because those informations have already been prepared.

*Please refrain from informing me about other bottlenecks like the network. They are not the issue. And they are no reason to use slow calls on another location in the code. Thank you.*

Comment: If you're reading from a network stream, the bottleneck will most likely be your network, not `MethodInfo.Invoke`. Optimizing the latter will probably make no observable difference in performance.

Comment: In addition to Michael's answer - All answers will likely boil down to "Not invoking methods dynamically are going to be the fastest"

Comment: What Michael Liu said, but you might also consider so-called open delegates for delegates to instance methods (https://blog.slaks.net/2011/06/open-delegates-vs-closed-delegates.html), if the number of possible "normal"/closed delegates (delegates containing a reference to the target object instance) could be an issue...

Comment: Because we already have 3 comments stating and supporting that the network will be the bottleneck: No it won't - thank you. And you will have to believe me on this.

Comment: @elgonzo: I test your suggestion. It may work. You can formulate an answer to this question. I will confirm your answer when I can get it to work.

Comment: I'll write an answer if you confirmed that it works and performance is sufficient for you. I am lazy. Really lazy. :-D Also, i don't really know how the performance will be when using open delegates compared to your other best approach(es) so far. My comment was more a response to you mentioning that you tried delegates, but which was not suitable due to the amount of delegates you had to store.

Comment: Your open delegate idea is working and about factor 14 times faster than `MethodInfo.Invoke`. Sometimes it's that easy to help.

Comment: Okay, now you forced me to write an answer :-))). But not today anymore, it's too late and my brain is already shutting down. I'll get to it tomorrow... you know, because Mondays suck... ;-)

Comment: This is a silly question performant how? Speed, memory, large number of requests... Fast is not more performant. Most of the code you posted looks like it was written in 2008 what runtime are you using? None of this looks like high performance code.

Comment: Read up on [micro benchmarking](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) because what you are doing is wrong from the get go.

Comment: I really can't help my self, but why are you even arguing about pseudo-code. And how will you know that something is wrong or not? You even don't have all the necessary information to give that kind of a statement.

Comment: Hey, it seems Scharle saved me from writing an answer... :-)

Comment: An interesting talk on the subject https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wxqv29V3a7c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use open delegates, which are about ten times faster than `MethodInfo.Invoke`. You would create such a `delegate` from a `MethodInfo` like this:

```
delegate void OpenCommandCall(Callee element, parameters);

OpenCommandCall occDelegate = (OpenCommandCall)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(OpenCommandCall), methodInfo));
```

You then would call this delegate like:

```
occDelegate.Invoke(callee, params);
```

Where `callee` is the element you want to call the method on, `methodInfo` is the `MethodInfo` of the method and `parameters` are a placeholder for various other parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you want to give a try to the [ObjectMethodExecutor](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/ff87989d893b000aac1bfef0157c92be1f04f714/shared/Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectMethodExecutor.Sources/ObjectMethodExecutor.cs?WT.mc_id=-blog-scottha)

According to [Hanselman](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETCoreArchitectDavidFowlersHiddenGemsIn21.aspx):

> If you ever need to invoke a method on a type via reflection and that method could be async, we have a helper that we use everywhere in the ASP.NET Core code base that is highly optimized and flexible called the ObjectMethodExecutor.
>
> The team uses this code in MVC to invoke your controller methods. They use this code in SignalR to invoke your hub methods. It handles async and sync methods. It also handles custom awaitables and F# async workflows